# Tierpricing between customer groups problem

Tags: magento-1.7, price, tierprice, customer-group

I am using 2 shops within one Magento.
One for end-users and the other for my retailers.
On the retailer website, I need to separate the user group into wholesale and retail, I added a customer group wholesale with the retail tax scheme.

Old case:
One product A price 29.95 for normal price.
Tier-price for retail group 3 pcs 15.00.
On the List (frontpage) or product view no problem.
On the cart (put 3 pcs in the cart) price is 15.00 p.p.

New case:
I change prices retail group in the wholesale group (remain the prices itself).
I changed the customer to the wholesale group.
After clearing cache (and reindex the whole bunch), On the List (frontpage) and product view, no problem price is 15.00 for 3
On the cart (put 3 pcs in the cart) I see 29.95 p.p.
Tax behavior is correct (system adds the taxes needed)

Any hints about where to look for this strange situation?
I am using Magento 1.7.0.2

edit:
When I am changing the product tier prices user group to the retailer but remain the customer within the wholesale group the prices are wrong on the product view page but correct in the cart??

Comment: I don'T understand the problem. Can you please add a few screenshots? Just in case you are reading this, I'll close the question, if you need and want an answer, just edit it, add images and request reopening.

Comment: i did reorganized my politics and reorganized my skins and templates. Probable it was wrong in my templates, because after changing the template the error was gone.